# "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'" after calling logging config function

Tags: python, logging, import

I want to import a logger function logger_main(name) from file Logger.py to another file in the same directory /GeneralScripts. The dir is marked as Source in PyCharm and a file **init**.py is also added in /GeneralScripts.

So I import it from GeneralScripts.Logger import logger_main

The logger looks like this:

```py
def logger_main(name):
    for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
        logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
    logger = logging.basicConfig(filename='{}.log'.format(name),
                                 level=logging.INFO,
                                 format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
                                 datefmt='%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')
    return logger
```

And the file where I import it looks like this:

```py
# import modules
import os
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import json
from GeneralScripts.Logger import logger_main
import logging

# credentials
with open('cred_db', 'r') as file:
    cred_db = json.load(file)


# set the logger
logging = logger_main('DB')

def connect_to_db():
    """Connects to the database Controlling_Marketing.
    :return: engine instance
    """
    try:
        params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PWD={pwd};Port={port};'.format(**cred_db))
        engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params))
        logging.info('Connected to the DB Controlling_Marketing')
        return engine
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Exception occurred, check def connect_to_db", exc_info=True)

# run it
engine = connect_to_db()
```

When I run it, exceptions occur

```py
logging.info('Connected to the DB Controlling_Marketing')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'

logging.error("Exception occurred, check def connect_to_db", exc_info=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

I checked importing other functions, it worked ok, the problem is only with the logger. 
I have no idea why

Comment: Well, first of all I would try to rename your `logging` variable to have no conflict with the `logging` module

Comment: Have just tried to rename, but, unfortunately, it doesn't help. It keeps throwing sa,e errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig` doesn’t return anything (technically it returns `None`). Therefore the return value of `logger_main` is `None` which explains the error you get.

You have:

> ```
> import logging
> …
> logging = logger_main('DB')  # now logging is None
> …
> logging.info('...')          # --> 'NoneType' has no attribute 'info'
> ```

Do not assign the result of `logger_main('DB')` to `logging`, so that `logging` still refers to the logging module when you call `logging.info`:

```
import logging
…
logger_main('DB')    # do not assign
…
logging.info('...')  # now logging is the logging module
```

Comment: Have just tried to rename, but, unfortunately, it doesn't help. It keeps throwing sa,e errors.

Comment: What exactly did you change? Please edit your question to show the actual code you are using, and please include the error message with full traceback.

Comment: have read wrong, now gotcha, deleted the variable. Now it works, thank you!